# I can't throws Exception and IOException in Java

Tags: java, maven, exception, web-scraping, jsoup

I can't throws Exceptions such as IOException and Exception. I need to add dependencies of these but I couldn't find it.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;  > It throws error: Cannot resolve symbol 'java' - Add Maven dependency

public class JsoupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  > Cannot resolve symbol 'IOException' 
        // download the HTML from wikipedia and parses it
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        // Select a bunch of a tags
        final Elements newsHeadLines = document.select("#mp-itn b a");
        // Prints to console

        for(Element headline : newsHeadLines) {  > foreach not applicable to type 'org.jsoup.select.Elements'
            System.out.println(headline);  > Cannot resolve symbol 'System'
        }
    }
}
```

My question can be basic but I'm pretty new on this sorry. If you give my answer please add these:

1. Where did you find this that dependency?
2. How can I find dependencies, because I checked Maven repository but I couldn't find.
3. Compiler throws error even for System.out.println method as I showed above, why is that?
4. Compiler throws error which I showed on belove, `foreach not applicable to type 'org.jsoup.select.Elements'`

Thank you for your all answers. I don't want directly dependency. I want it to know why. Thanks

Comment: If you are saying that ***THIS LINE:*** `import java.io.IOException` is giving your problems... Well, that is truly a new one to me :).  That ***IS NOT*** a `CLASSPATH` or "dependency" problem.  I need to ask you, are you even capable of invoking the `Java Compiler` (`javac` command) at the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add a dependency to use `IOException` or `System`.

You probably did not use the compiler correctly or your IDE shows non-existent errors.

Comment: Well yes, I have 3 computers so the computer which I tried I couldn't invoke javac -version. Thank you